# How to capture the first link in xpath?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I have this html code:

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li>
       <a href="/ru/products/pro_1" title="text_1">...</a>
       <ul class="sm-nowrap">...</ul>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="/ru/products/pro_2" title="text_2">...</a>
       <ul class="sm-nowrap">...</ul>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="/ru/products/pro_3" title="text_3">...</a>
       <ul class="sm-nowrap">...</ul>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="/ru/products/pro_4" title="text_4">...</a>
       <ul class="sm-nowrap">...</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to collect all the links (which are above the `<ul class="sm-nowrap">`
tag). I'm trying to do this with the following loop:

```
for i in response.css('ul#main-menu li'):
    link = i.xpath('//ul[class="sm-nowrap"]/preceding::a[1]/@href').get()
```

but I only get `None None None None....`
where is my mistake, what is wrong?

Comment: There was a typo in my earlier suggestion. Try this `.//ul[@class="sm-nowrap"]/preceding::a[1]/@href`. You forgot to add `@` sign before class and a ***`.`*** just before `//`.

Comment: @SIM: make an answer out of your comment and explain a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**!! I don't have your whole HTML code so considering the part you gave us: !!**

```
from io import StringIO
from lxml import etree

f = StringIO('''\
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li>
       <a href="/ru/products/pro_1" title="text_1">...</a>
       <ul class="sm-nowrap">...</ul>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="/ru/products/pro_2" title="text_2">...</a>
       <ul class="sm-nowrap">...</ul>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="/ru/products/pro_3" title="text_3">...</a>
       <ul class="sm-nowrap">...</ul>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="/ru/products/pro_4" title="text_4">...</a>
       <ul class="sm-nowrap">...</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
''')

tree = etree.parse(f)
```

The easiest and fastest way:

```
links = [i for i in tree.xpath('//a/@href')]
```

Explanation:

`//` everything from root to first `a` **tag**(s) (*same level*) encountered, then get the `href` **attribute** .

Result:

```
['/ru/products/pro_1', '/ru/products/pro_2', '/ru/products/pro_3', '/ru/products/pro_4']
```